# JavaScript HTML, clickable button from IMG tag

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to do a clickable button with javascript. I am doing the following

```
document.getElementById("nav").onmousedown = function() { this.src="img1.png"; return false;}
document.getElementById("nav").onmouseout = function() { this.src="img.png"; return false;
}
```

What am I missing with events? By the way, I did it before by encapsulating events in single `initAll` foo makes the button clickable but slow on the server.... When I click it opens the link before I see my button pressed animation... Any info?

Answer (score 2):

Do you really want to use javascript here? Maybe CSS will fit your needs better?

```
#nav {
    background: url('img1.png') no-repeat 0 0;
}
#nav:active {
    background: url('img2.png') no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you are right... I am trying the headbang stuff here obviously.
Any info however how to properly set the events:
onmouseover, then if clicked change image, and when moussebutton up, return image, goto link...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using jquery's .animate, and then in the callback function sending the user to the link?

Comment: here is my site:
www.difinancial.comdc.net
the button is clickable, but I don`t think it`s very responsive. If there are some gurus, can you confirm it`s normal?

Comment: Looks normal to me, clickable, seems to "press" down when I click it, and then release when I let off click.

Comment: strange... guess it`s my netbook, touchpad`s fault for not responsing good... Thanks Travis J :)

Comment: Why would you suggest someone to use JQuery for this when they don't yet have a firm enough grasp on basic events? Do you want people to not learn?

Comment: @Rage: a) .animate is a cool function b) it is really not that hard to learn, very slight learning curve there as it is only 1 call c) using mouse events implies some grasp of "basic events" d) I love it when people learn new things, which is why I suggested something new e) Your comment is non constructive.

Comment: Thanks everybody for the replies. Since it`s  working actually, I though that the script was choppy but looks like just my pc was slow.. Please can you revisit it
http://www.difinancial.comdc.net
and confirm that buttons are actually ok?

Comment: @TravisJ thanks for testing them, I`ve added window.location changers onmouseup, but not on mouse out, because it seemed like a bug if you press and hold mouse and mouseout of the button... now fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `this` with `document.getElementById("nav")` and see if it does anything.

Comment: I don`t see logic by replacing this with doc. element, it`s the same, actually it works buttons are clickable, I am just wondering if that`s good code for optimization or not.

Comment: Some browsers IIRC expect a more verbose reference and don't accept `this`. Correct me if I'm wrong.